# How to check app background time react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am stuck with a new requirement in case of app is in background mode for more then 1 min user should be logout from the app. I am checking user with Asyncstorage but i can't check calculated background time.

I have searched many of the libraries but still confused how to integrate.
If anyone have solution for the same please let me know.

Comment: What have you tried in your code so far and what isn't working?  Any errors?

Comment: I need to check the total time of app in background. I used react native AppState

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use this [library](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer).

 It allows you to run `setTimeout` in a background.

The first step is to determine when the user goes background. For this purpose, you should use [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html).
Then run your background timer and log out the user in 1 minute, then stop the timer. If it is hard to understand I will make some draft code for you, but I believe everything should be clear.

Comment: Appstate is working when i come back again. I am using AppState in app.js and when i am going to background it's not showing anything.